# Bootstrap chevron icon doesn't change onclick, why?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this section:

```
<div id="weather">
<h4><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i> Weather</h4>
```

and code to this:

```
$('#weather h4').click(function (){
    $('#weather .entries').toggle();
    $('#weather .icon-chevron-down').toggleClass('icon-chevron-right');
});
```

[jsbin1](http://jsbin.com/acufaw/1/edit)

and it doesn't work, but if I change places for icon-chevron, it works:

[jsbin2](http://jsbin.com/exucew/1/edit)

is it a bug or am I doing something wrong??

Comment: try .toggleClass("icon-chevron-right icon-chevron-down")
note, that you have to change the selector in front of toggleClass ;-)

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024218/bootstrap-3-collapse-change-chevron-icon-on-click/20925245#20925245

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is working:

http://jsbin.com/omerep/1/edit

```
$('#weather h4').click(function (){
    $('#weather .entries').toggle();
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-chevron-right icon-chevron-down', 200);
});
```