# Change Font Awesome icon when collapsing a card table row in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue with changing the font awesome icon when collapsing a row in card table.

How can I create this with javascript? That, when, I click on a row the icon is changed for the item that is collapsed, and for the one that is open.

I have the following code:

Icon for opening : **fas fa-chevron-down**

Icon when the row is closed : **fas fa-chevron-right**

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="list-group-item" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><label style="margin-left:20px;">Configure which userdata to show for voice interactions</label>
        </label>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-block">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div>
              <div class="card-block">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><b>Label</b></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><b>Userdata</b></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                      <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#optionModal" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> <b>Optie</b> toevoegen</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        Label sdlsdkfjsdlfksdj
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        Userdata dflskdfjds
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt" style="font-size:20px;"></i></i></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-trash-alt" style="font-size:20px; margin-left:20px;"></i></i></span>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        Label sdlsdkfjsdlfksdj
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        Userdata dflskdfjds
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt" style="font-size:20px;"></i></i></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-trash-alt" style="font-size:20px; margin-left:20px;"></i></i></span>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        Label sdlsdkfjsdlfksdj
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        Userdata dflskdfjds
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt" style="font-size:20px;"></i></i></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-trash-alt" style="font-size:20px; margin-left:20px;"></i></i></span>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        Label sdlsdkfjsdlfksdj
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        Userdata dflskdfjds
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt" style="font-size:20px;"></i></i></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-trash-alt" style="font-size:20px; margin-left:20px;"></i></i></span>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="list-group-item" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <label class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><label style="margin-left:20px;">Con</label>
        </label>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        other item here ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="list-group-item" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <label class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><label style="margin-left:20px;">ctions</label>
        </label>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        other item here ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I have to far :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.collapse')
        .on('shown.bs.collapse', function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          console.log("open");
            $(this)
                .parent().parent()
                .find(".fa-chevron-down")
                .removeClass("fa-chevron-down")
                .addClass("fa-chevron-right");
        }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(event) {
            console.log("closed");
         event.stopPropagation();
            $(this)
                .parent().parent()
                .find(".fa-chevron-right")
                .removeClass("fa-chevron-right")
                .addClass("fa-chevron-down");
        });
});

</script>
```

But it collapses for all the records, how to chance this for only the records that is open/closed.

Comment: What have you tried so far the change the icons? Have you read the other related questions such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024218/bootstrap-3-collapse-change-chevron-icon-on-click/ ?

Comment: Yes but they don't seem to work..

Comment: updated my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to go up 1 parent level...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.collapse')
        .on('shown.bs.collapse', function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          console.log("open");
            $(this)
                .parent()
                .find(".fa-chevron-down")
                .removeClass("fa-chevron-down")
                .addClass("fa-chevron-right");
        }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(event) {
            console.log("closed");
         event.stopPropagation();
            $(this)
                .parent()
                .find(".fa-chevron-right")
                .removeClass("fa-chevron-right")
                .addClass("fa-chevron-down");
        });
});
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ePRWZuEK2K