# bootstrap accordion not collapsing on first load

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, accordion

Here is my html view:

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-right").removeClass("fa-chevron-right").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
    });
```

```css
a.accordion-toggle {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif !important;
}

a.accordion-toggle.collapsed {
    color: #254fac !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
           <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
            Environmentally Friendly
           </a>
         </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    Reliable buying and selling
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                            Quality assuarance
                          </a>
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

screenshot of my page:

[image]

On initial page load, I want the first accordion is to collapse.

I use 
jquery: v3.2.1 ,
jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js , 
popper.min.js
and 
bootstrap > v4.2.1

I have updated the code above please check this one. My problem is in after first load first accordion is not collapsing but after click any accordion it will work but i want first load first one is collapsed.

Comment: Does anything here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024218/bootstrap-3-collapse-change-chevron-icon-on-click  or here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325779/bootstrap-3-collapse-show-state-with-chevron-icon Can you make a codepen like this? https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/QQOZRe  Or, can you turn your code into a runnable snippet?

Comment: Is just changing `<span class="icon icon-chevron-up">` for `<span class="icon icon-chevron-right">` for the first `<span>` in your markup would be a fix?

Comment: I have updated the snippet please check above my question @jqueryHtmlCSS

Comment: The snippet is almost working.  It's very unusual for the arrow to point up.  Why is the arrow pointing up?  Your code looks great, your English is confusing.

Comment: brother please check my question again, i said my accordion is working but i want after first load first accordion should be collapsed it should open on first load, Did you understand? @jqueryHtmlCSS

Answer (score 0):

You can just collapse all accordion on load -

```
$(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
```

Final Code -

```js
$(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-right").removeClass("fa-chevron-right").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
});
```

```css
a.accordion-toggle {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif !important;
}

a.accordion-toggle.collapsed {
  color: #254fac !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
          Environmentally Friendly
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
          Reliable buying and selling
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
          Quality assuarance
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT 1 :

I also realized you are adding `fa-chevron-up` class to your first accordion. You can change it to `fa-chevron-right` and that should solve your problem.

Final Code -

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-right").removeClass("fa-chevron-right").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
});
```

```css
a.accordion-toggle {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif !important;
}

a.accordion-toggle.collapsed {
  color: #254fac !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
          Environmentally Friendly
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
          Reliable buying and selling
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
          Quality assuarance
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT 2:

If you want to expand your first accordion just add class `show` to your first accordion.

Final Code -

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-right").removeClass("fa-chevron-right").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-right");
});
```

```css
a.accordion-toggle {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif !important;
}

a.accordion-toggle.collapsed {
  color: #254fac !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
          Environmentally Friendly
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse show">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
          Reliable buying and selling
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
          Quality assuarance
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: but your snippet not working first accordion not collapsed ?

Comment: brother first accordion and icon should be collapsed icon is right it collapsed but text is not showing on first load

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood the problem. I will update the code

Comment: You want the first accordion to expand right? and not collapse?

Comment: @shawn, I have updated my answer to expand first accordion.

Comment: brother it always active while i am click another it wont stop collapsing -_- :(

Comment: i think you didn't understand me

Answer (score 0):

Just change;

```
       <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
        Environmentally Friendly
       </a>
```

to be;

```
       <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
        Environmentally Friendly
       </a>
```